# Why can't I access EOF using fseek()?

Tags: c, file, eof

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * fp = fopen("Introduce.txt","rt");

    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    int i = feof(fp);
    printf("%d",i);

    fseek(fp,1,SEEK_END);
    i = feof(fp);
    printf("%d",i);

    fseek(fp,-1,SEEK_END);
    i = feof(fp);
    printf("%d",i);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to access EOF positioning 'file position indicator' at the end of the file.
But the result of this code is "000".
Why does this happen?

Comment: you have to read from the file to get EOF.

Comment: **7.21.9.2 The fseek function p5**  _clears the end-of-file indicator for the
stream, and then establishes the new position._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `feof()` function doesn't report that it is at EOF until you try to read some data and there is no data to read.

You can seek beyond the current EOF of a file that's open for writing (or that's open for reading and writing).

See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) for more information on why you seldom if ever need to use `feof()`.  In some ways, `feof()` is a function you should forget about — most of your programs will improve if you assume it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

[This documentation on `feof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof) is very clear (**emphasis mine**):

> This function only reports the stream state as reported by the most
>   recent I/O operation, it does not examine the associated data source.
>   For example, if the most recent I/O was a `fgetc`, which returned the
>   last byte of a file, `feof` returns zero. **The next `fgetc` fails and
>   changes the stream state to end-of-file. Only then `feof` returns
>   non-zero.**
>
> In typical usage, input stream processing stops on any error; `feof` and
>   `ferror` are then used to distinguish between different error
>   conditions.